Error on running Matplotlib on Spyder , " no attribute " " get_data_path"
I'm getting this error when I try to run on Spyder, how can I solve this?
  File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\_api\__init__.py:217 in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(

AttributeError: module 'matplotlib' has no attribute 'get_data_path'

Trying to make work, I'm learning it, but getting this error.

Welcome to Stack Overflow. Are you using a virtual environment? Did you recently install or update spyder?

Hello, yes im using win 11 pro on hyper v , recently installed it and having difficulties with configuring all the environment on my virtual machine for study.

Are you using conda? Pip? Something else?

i got this error on spyder , i tried to open again a basic project for test and displays the error

But how did you install Spyder? Through your virtual environment?
